# Python NLTK module wordnet.morphy() method takes 10 seconds to execute on AWS Lambda. Any alternatives or insights into why this happens?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, nltk

```
def lambda_handler(event=None, context=None):

from nltk.corpus import wordnet

cat = wordnet.morphy('cats')

print('morphy', cat)

bag = 'hello world'
return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": bag
}
```

I am simply trying to run the `wordnet.morphy('cats')` method on AWS Lambda using the NLTK library. When I run locally, the method runs under a second. However, when I run on AWS Lambda, it takes over 10 seconds to execute. Does anyone know why this happens or what other alternatives work on AWS lambda to tokenize a word?

If you would like to see the deployment package being uploaded to AWS Lambda please follow this github repo: https://github.com/jenkins6g/NLTKDebugging. Any help or insights are greatly appreciated.